# Unhandled Process Fault Exceptions in flows after Summer 14

Tags: visual-workflow, flow, summer14

I have been receiving lots of complaints from our Call Center agents and many others trying to use Flows after Summer 14.

The errors that they are seeing are

> "nested exception is:
>           common.exception.ApiQueryException: sObject type 'Flow__Case_Type_Co_Counsel__c' is not supported. If you are
>   attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after
>   the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for
>   the appropriate names. (There was a problem executing your command.) >
>   RETRIEVE
>
> caused by element : FlowRecordLookup.Lookup_CaseType_CoCounsel
>
> caused by: ; nested exception is:
>           common.exception.ApiQueryException: sObject type 'Flow__Case_Type_Co_Counsel__c' is not supported. If you are
>   attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after
>   the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for
>   the appropriate names. (There was a problem executing your command.) >
>   RETRIEVE"

Its weird because we have the Custom Objects defined right in our org and I am not sure whats adding the Flow___ prefix to these Custom objects.

Did something break with Flows as part of Summer 14 release?

Comment: One another update I received, its a Salesforce bug introduced with release 190(Summer 14). There is only a temporary fix that can be applied by Salesforce Support. The fix would break as soon as you deploy something to the org again.

Comment: OK. There is a patch that is applied by Salesforce Support which permanently fixed this problem, if anyone is facing the same problem, please contact support and they can apply the patch to your org.

Comment: Logontokartik - do you have a code or identifier for that  patch?  I have a client with the same problem and our support engineer hasn't been able to figure it out, so I want to mention something specific to him.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've been getting this error as well, in particular with the new .start() method for calling flows from Apex.

The word I've heard is that this is likely a bug and it's being investigated. I've heard other Flow related issues with the Summer release as well. You can see the known issues with flow here: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?keywords=flow

Unfortunately, I haven't figured out a workaround for this yet. It seems to occur whenever I'm doing a Fast Lookup.

Comment: I opened up a case with Salesforce Support, and they said its because of the Summer release but didnt figure out why its happening, they said they are going to apply a patch to our org to fix it. Hopefully it should.

Comment: I got the exact same response to my query to support. Guess we'll just have to waitfor the patch

Answer (score 0):

There is a current workaround that I discovered with the.  Just update the version of your Flow and activate.  It is not a scalable flow because this has to be done every 8-14 hours. but it works

Comment: Yes. that would work if we are doing handful, but its painful as we have 80+ flows in our org

Comment: We have 60+ flows in our org, but for some reason it's not impacting all.  Still no answer from Salesforce...